# virtual template function workaround

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

I stumbled upon a problem I (nor do any of my more knowledgeable colleagues) know how to solve (of work around). The problem in the end comes to not being able to create a virtual template function. I have searched the net thoroughly, found several ways of dealing with it, but none seem to be applicable in my case.

I don't know how to describe this situation in short, but I'll do my best and hope it makes sense.

The problem is processing two curves, each of them consists of one or several segments of same or different curve types. So I began with creating an interface for a curve segment, with a template class of the curve it will be interacting with (functions are of the same type as intersections between two different curve segments, for example):

```
template<class curve> class curve_segment { // some methods here }
```

user can then implement several types of curves, and appropriate functions depending with what curves it will be interacting with. For example, `circle` and `line`, where both can interact with both:

```
class line :  public curve_segment<line>, public curve_segment<circle> { //... }
class circle :  public curve_segment<line>, public curve_segment<circle> { //... }
```

Following that, I have a class `cell`, which depends on two curve segments, and a base class `cell_base` which encapsulates it:

```
template<class curve1, class curve2> class cell : public cell_base { 
  cell_base* up; cell_base* down;

  curve_segment<curve1>* segment_x;
  curve_segment<curve2>* segment_y;

  // some methods that depend on both curves
}
```

In the end, there is a 2D grid m*n of such cells, where the two curves consist of m and n `curve_segments` of possibly different types, and is held together by the two pointers in each cell.

The problem begins to show when a new curve_segment would be added to one of the two curves. The obvious solution would be to add

```
template<class curve> virtual void add_curve_x(curve_segment<curve> seg) =0;
```

to the `cell_base` class, where the implementation in `cell` could extract the appropriate segment of the other curve, and appended a new cell to it. For example, if curves `a` and `b` where `a` represents the x axis in the grid, and we were to add another curve segment to the curve `a`, we could find the right hand most cells of the grid, extract the curve on the y axis of each such cell, and from that and the newly provided segment make a new cell, which would append to it's right.

Type erasure wouldn't work since we would need to know the type of the newly added segment at the point of the `cell` creation (we would need to provide types of both segments as template parameters to the `cell` class).

Moving template to the `cell_base` class also wouldn't work, since that would mean that at the time of each `cell` allocation I would have to know the type of the next `curve_segment`.

Is there a way around this?

**edit**:
As suggested, adding the `add_curve_x` method:

```
template<class curve1, class curve2>
template<class curve> 
cell<curve1, curve>* cell<curve1, curve2>::add_curve_x(curve_segment<curve1>* seg) {
  return new cell<curve1, curve>(seg, (curve_segment<curve>*)(this->segment_y));
}
```

In this case `seg` has to be of type `curve`, which has to implement `curve_segment<curve1>`. `segment_y` also has to implement `curve_segment<curve>`.

**edit 2**: explanation of why the cast is there

[pic](http://i48.tinypic.com/14y4kmv.png)

Take the case with non-bolded rectangles. In that situations, there are two curves, curve `a` with 2 segments and curve `b` with 3 segments. class `line` has to implement `curve_segment<line>` as well as `curve_segment<circle>`, and circle has to implement both as well. Now let's add another bezier curve segment to curve `a`. class `bezier` has to implement `curve_segment<line>` and `curve_segment<circle>`, and `line` and `circle` have to implement `curve_segment<bezier>`.

Let's look how we create the middle of the bolded three `cells`. We would make a call

```
add_curve_x<bezier>(new bezier(...));
```

on the cell object of type `cell<circle, circle>`.

The argument `seg` will be a new `bezier` object (which can be cast to `curve_segment<circle>`), and that is also what `curve` type is, and `segment_y` will have to be cast to `curve_segment<bezier>`, since that's the curve type it's interacting with in the newly created cell.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please show a concrete implementation of `add_curve_x` in `cell` (just imagine template virtual functions are allowed).

Comment: Still unclear... what is this cast doing there? Can you cast any curve segment to any other one?

Comment: One curve can implement several `curve_segments` with different parameters. The implementation depends on what kind of curves might interact with each other. In this case, curves in the cell interact with `curve1` and `curve2`, but when we add a different type of a curve segment (`curve`), `segment_y` also has to interact with that one. Imagine you have one curve consisting of two lines and one circle, and the second one of a bezier curve and a circle and a line. Then everything has to be able to interact with everything.

Comment: In the end I can always force all curve segment to be of the same type and not have this problem, but that would reduce usefulness considerably.

Comment: If you call `cell<line, circle>::add_curve_x<bezier>`, the cast will try to convert `curve_segment<circle>*` to `curve_segment<bezier*>`. Because the two classes are not related, this will work as `reinterpret_cast`, and produce undefined behaviour.

Comment: Anyway, I think you can apply the Visitor pattern here, since there's a kind of double-dispatch (two curve segments of type `curve1` and `curve2` together produce a `cell<curve1, curve2>`).

Comment: I agree about reinterpret_cast, it would be a bad idea. I'm trying to figure out how a visitor pattern would help this situation... Did you mean that `cell` would call a visitor and that would have implementation for every specific `cell<c1, c2>`?

Comment: I should probably also mention that all this should be transparent to the user. The user should not have to do anything else apart from implementing specific curve_segments (like `line`, `circle`, `bezier`, etc, these could be very specific).

Comment: I think more about having an implementation for each specific curve_segment.

Comment: As far as I understand the visitor pattern helps to add new functionality to existing object structures. This would mean that for each concrete instance of curve segment there would need to be a virtual method in the visitor interface. Since I have no idea what this curve segments would be apriori, this would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `curve_segment_base`:

```
class curve_segment_base {
   // for double dispatching here:
  virtual cell_base* add_curve_x(cell_base* cell) = 0;
};

template<class curve> 
class curve_segment : public virtual curve_segment_base { 
     // some specific methods here 
     // for double dispatching here:
     virtual cell_base* add_curve_x(cell_base* cell)
     {
         // this has to be moved to cpp file due to dependency from cell_base
         return cell->add_curve_x(this); // now the correct method from cell is called
     }
};
```

So you can add this method as virtual to your cell_base

```
class cell_base {
   virtual cell_base* add_curve_x(curve_segment_base* seg) = 0;

   // methods necessary for double dispatching here:
   virtual cell_base* add_curve_x(curve_segment<line>* seg) = 0;
   virtual cell_base* add_curve_x(curve_segment<circle>* seg) = 0;
   ...
};
```

So your method would look like, with double dispatching here:

```
template<class curve1, class curve2>
virtual cell_base* cell<curve1, curve2>::add_curve_x(curve_segment_base* seg) {
  return seg->add_curve_x(this);
}
```

And you will have to implement all the real implementation methods for all segments:

```
template<class curve1, class curve2>
virtual cell_base* cell<curve1, curve2>::add_curve_x(curve_segment<line>* seg) {
  return new cell<curve1, line>(...);
}
template<class curve1, class curve2>
virtual cell_base* cell<curve1, curve2>::add_curve_x(curve_segment<circle>* seg) {
  return new cell<curve1, circle>(...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a nice solution, but it's something I was trying to avoid, since user would have to implement `add_curve_x`, where there is actually no need for it. I guess I should have chosen a more appropriate language :)